# SQL/PHP: Bound variables don't match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

This is part of an account search feature for a website. Both $param and $str are defined. This part of the script calls for a count from the table on the column that the search is being performed on.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`?`) FROM `users` WHERE `?` LIKE '?'");
    $query->bindValue(1, $param);
    $query->bindValue(2, $param);
    $query->bindValue(3, $str);
$query->execute();
$total = $query->fetchColumn();
```

The problem is that I'm receiving the following SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

I've been trying to debug this for a good portion of the day.  I know all my variables are defined, and I'm associating them with tokens in the statements, and no tokens are missing variables.  Anyone have any idea why I'm getting this error? :(

Comment: Does it work if you replace `COUNT(\`?\`)` with `COUNT(*)` and remove its bindValue?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply.  I did as you suggested, Chris, and it resulted in the same error message.  I ended up not solving this issue, but I did work around it by replacing bindValue with bindParam and defined the parameters in the statement.